# Ajax CalendarExtender not displaying 2nd row on

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview

I have a Ajax CalendarExtender,  ID'd to a textbox and data sourced to more than one record.
If the textbox's are all blank, no assigned value. The textbox's will popup the calendar with click.

If the textbox's contain a value, the first textbox will  pop a blank calendar and the rest will pop nothing.

I have stand-alone textbox's with the ajax calendar and they work fine. Here is what I have with assigned value.

```
               <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false">
                       <Columns>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Maturity Date">
                           <ItemTemplate >
                             <asp:TextBox ID="txtMatureDate"  text="4" runat ="server"></asp:TextBox>
                             <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="maturitydate" TargetControlID="txtMatureDate" Format="MMMM,yyyy"  runat ="server" DefaultView="Months" />
                          </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                      </Columns>
                   </asp:GridView>
```

Here is datasource.

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim SqlDataSource3 As New SqlDataSource()
    SqlDataSource3.ID = "SqlDataSource3"
    Me.Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource3)
    SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = "select maturitydate from PFW_LPMCalc_test where  maturitydate >= '02/01/2017' and maturitydate <= '07/31/2017' order by maturitydate desc"
    SqlDataSource3.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("jdwholegoods").ConnectionString
    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource3,
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

I have scriptmanager in place and

Comment: I put this code in another project and it works. So  I have added something to this project creating this problem... sheesh.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. so I uninstalled the Ajax Toolkit and reinstalled. It had a newer version though I don't think that did it. My guess is something was on top of current version and it needed to be back on top.